# ffmpeg MOOV Atom on a ProRes file?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, quicktime

We have been asked by a client to create a ProRes QT file (.mov) but specifically asked to "***The moov atom (movie index file) should be placed at the beginning of the file.***"
I have been reading around but could not find a solution for .mov files. Everybody is talking for .mp4.

The line I came with is:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.mov -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:6 -map 0:a:7 -movflags faststart output_ATOM.mov
```

The audio mapping and the video copying is working fine. I need to know if the ***-movflags faststart*** is actually going to do the job?
I can't find a way to check the result if it actually moved the Atom.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. During the process, you should see the line below near the end of ffmpeg's logging.

```
Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file
```

Comment: Thanks Gyan! And is there a way to actually check the result if it has the moov atom at the beginning?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/56963790

Comment: Thanks but I get a 'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Any idea?

Comment: Which OS are you on?

Comment: windows 10. Thanks.

Comment: Also, I found another way of checking. Open the mov file with a hex editor and the moov should be at the start.